# Can't figure out what causes the segmentation fault | from HW

Tags: c

I have the following data types:

### formation.h

```
typedef struct formation_t {
    Player players[FORMATION_NUM_PLAYERS];
    int numPlayers;                /* How many players are in the above array */
    int timesPlayed;
    int timesWon;
}* Formation;
```

---

### team.h

```
typedef struct team_t {
    char* name;
    char* coachName;
    Formation* formations;
    int currFormations;
    int maxFormations;
}* Team;
```

---

And the following functions:

---

```
Team teamCreate(char* name, char* coach, int maxFormations)
{
    //Check if parameters make sense.
    if (name == NULL || coach == NULL || maxFormations < 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //Try allocating memory for name.
    char* teamName = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    if (teamName == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(teamName, name);

    //Try allocating memory for coachName.
    char* coachName = malloc(strlen(coach) + 1);
    if (coachName == NULL)
    {
        free(teamName);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(coachName, coach);

    //Try allocating memory for formations.
    Formation* formations = malloc(sizeof(Formation) * maxFormations);
    if (formations == NULL)
    {
        free(teamName);
        free(coachName);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Try allocating memory for team.
    Team newTeam = malloc(sizeof(struct team_t));
    if (newTeam == NULL)
    {
        free(teamName);
        free(coachName);
        free(formations);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Initialize newly created team.
    newTeam->name = teamName;
    newTeam->coachName = coachName;
    newTeam->maxFormations = maxFormations;
    newTeam->currFormations = 0;


    //Return created team.
    return newTeam;
}
```

---

```
TeamResult teamAddFormation(Team team, Formation formation)
{
    //Check for TEAM_NULL_ARGUMENT.
    if (team == NULL | formation == NULL)
    {
        return TEAM_NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }

    //Check for TEAM_IS_FULL.
    if (team->currFormations == team->maxFormations)
    {
        return TEAM_IS_FULL;
    }

    //Add formation.
    printf("\n -about to clone- \n");
    team->formations[team->currFormations] = formationClone(formation);
    printf("\n -clone completed- \n");
    team->currFormations = team->currFormations + 1;

    return TEAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

```
Formation formationClone(Formation formation)
{
    if (formation == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    Formation newFormation = malloc(sizeof(struct formation_t));
    if (newFormation == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    *newFormation = *formation;

    return newFormation;
}
```

---

When I try to test my work using the following code, I get a segmentation fault right after "about to clone".

```
Team team = teamCreate("Ac Milan", "Carletto", 2);

Formation formation1 = formationCreate();
ASSERT_NULL_ARGUMENT(teamAddFormation(NULL, formation1));
ASSERT_SUCCESS(teamAddFormation(team, formation1));
```

Comment: if (team == NULL | formation == NULL) should be if (team == NULL || formation == NULL)

Comment: @LeeNeverGup In this case, it doesn't matter.  Logical and bitwise OR would have the same result.

Comment: @Doppelganger The error is possibly if `team->currFormations` is too high.  Try printing that out.  Or, the error is in `formationClone`, and you haven't shown us the code for that.

Comment: I tried using "0" instead of team->currFormations, didn't make any difference.
Will post cloneFormation() in a second

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I added formationClone().

Comment: @Doppelganger WhozCraig gave you the right answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `teamCreate()` you never set your formations local variable into your Team structure after allocating it.

This is first:

```
//Try allocating memory for formations.
Formation* formations = malloc(sizeof(Formation) * maxFormations);
if (formations == NULL)
{
    free(teamName);
    free(coachName);
    return NULL;
}
```

then you do this after allocation the host-object:

```
//Initialize newly created team.
newTeam->name = teamName;
newTeam->coachName = coachName;
newTeam->maxFormations = maxFormations;
newTeam->currFormations = 0;


//Return created team.
return newTeam;
```

You never save the formation pointer to the structure member, so that pointer member is indeterminate and using it is invoking undefined behavior.

Add this to the bottom of that stack of assignments:

```
newTeam->formations = formations;
```

Comment: I can't believe I spent so much time because of this. Thanks!

Comment: @Doppelganger Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Glad to help. Review the rest of the code like this and make sure its as you want it. I didn't spend much time but hat leapt out at me. Again, glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try allocating memory for name.
char* teamName = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
if (teamName == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
strcpy(teamName, name);
```

teamName is pointing to an alocated char array. This array never deleted. This lead to a memory leak.